# QImage dithering quality

Tags: windows, image, qt, qimage

We are currently using a commercial library for image rendering with Windows. When displaying monochrome images in sizes smaller than the images original size, this library gray scales images so that still most of them can be recognized:

[image]

Now i tried the same with a Qt 4.8 Application.
Basically whats done is calling:

```
QImage mImage;
...
mImage.load(...);
...
painter.drawImage(paintRect, mImage, mImage.rect());
```

Where paintRect is smaller than mImage.rect(). That works well, but the output is much less satisfying:

[image]

I tried several renderHints (QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, Antialiasing, HighQualityAntialiasing) and also converted the Image using

```
mImage = mImage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform seemed to improve the output a little bit (its included in the screen shot). All the other things do not seem to change anything.

Am i missing something?

How can display of images with decrease size be improved?

Comment: are you preserving the aspect ratio? did you try prescaling the image with `QImage::scaled`

Comment: Keep aspect ratio: Not required by our application but in these cases i did, yes. No prescaling, a user zooms in and out and therefore scale factor always changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that during

```
painter.drawImage(paintRect, mImage, mImage.rect());
```

the painter just interpolate which pixel to take in the initial image when the size differs. Which will explain the second image.

Scale manual using

```
QImage todraw = mImage.scaled(
            paintRect.size(),
            Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
            Qt::SmoothTransformation);
...
painter.drawImage(paintRect, todraw, mImage.rect());
```

You compute the image `todraw` only on resize events (to avoid scaling every paint event)
and you use it instead with the painter.

Comment: Indeed that makes the difference. Amazing. I think this is a bug. Thanks

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR It is not a bug. QPainter::drawImage just doesn't do linear interpolation on image rescales. It has never had this behavior. Your use of SmoothPixmapTransform did not work because you are not working with pixmaps. Your use of the antialiasing settings had no effect because this issues is not related to antialiasing.